# Converting Pascal's variant record to Swift

Tags: swift, set

I am converting a program written in Pascal to Swift and some Pascal features do not have direct Swift equivalents such as variant records and defining sets as types.  A variant record in Pascal enables you to assign different field types to the same area of memory in a record. In other words, one particular location in a record could be either of type A or of type B. This can be useful in either/or cases, where a record can have either one field or the other field, but not both. What are the Swift equivalents for a variant record and a set type like setty in the Pascal fragment?

The Pascal code fragment to be converted is:

```
const
   strglgth    =     16;
   sethigh     =     47;
   setlow      =      0;

type
   setty = set of setlow..sethigh;
   cstclass = (reel,pset,strg);
   csp = ^constant;   /* pointer to constant type */
   constant = record case cclass: cstclass of
                 reel: (rval: packed array [1..strglgth] of char);
                 pset: (pval: setty);
                 strg: (slgth: 0..strglgth;
                 sval: packed array [1..strglgth] of char)
              end;

var 
   lvp: csp
```

My partial Swift code is

```
let strglgth    =     16
let sethigh     =     47
let setlow      =      0

enum cstclass : Int {case reel = 0, pset, strg}

var lvp: csp
```

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're looking for "enums with associated values" https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID148

Answer (score -1):

Variant records in Pascal are very simular to unions in C.

So this link will probably be helpful:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/using_imported_c_structs_and_unions_in_swift

In case the link ever goes dead, here's the relevant example:

```
union SchroedingersCat {
    bool isAlive;
    bool isDead;
};
```

In Swift, it’s imported like this:

```
struct SchroedingersCat {
    var isAlive: Bool { get set }
    var isDead: Bool { get set }

    init(isAlive: Bool)
    init(isDead: Bool)

    init()
}
```

That would be more like a functional port. It does not seem to take care of the fact that Variant records are actually meant to use the same piece of memory in different ways, so if you'd have some low-level code that reads from a stream or you have a pointer to such a structure, this might not help you.

In that case you might want to try just reserving some bytes, and write different getters/setters to access them. That would even work if you'd have to port more complex structures, like nested variant types.

But overall, if possible, I'd recommend to avoid porting such structures too literally, and use idioms that match Swift better.

Comment: In Swift you would idiomatically use an enum with associated values. Which is like a struct which contains a union and a enum tag, all in one

Comment: Note that if the case line in the record contains a definition (like X:Y) rather than something like "Integer" that means that line defines an extra (selector) field that occupies memory in the record/struct.

Comment: The issue remains somewhat unclear. Can someone please provide an example of how the constant structure should look like?